# Change Mac User Password using Perl Script

Tags: macos, perl, passwords

I'd like to be able to change a user's password using a Perl script. I've tried:

```
my $user = "test";
my $pass = "testing";

open(DATA, "| passwd $user") || die "failed";
print DATA $pass;
sleep(1);
print DATA $pass;
close(DATA);
```

and it never goes through.

I have also tried `echo -e "$pass\n$pass" | passwd $user" however, I receive a password conversion failure error.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe since you do not have a newline character it never fully receives the new password. It's like you typed it in but never hit enter.

[Expect](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod) is often used for prompts like this I believe.

Comment: I managed to get it working with Expect. Except expect doesn't allow me to change multiple user accounts at once. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you not feed the arguments to a function and iterate over a list of accounts each calling the function and using Expect?